# How to append css class dynamically to hidden field in mvc using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

in this following hidden field there is a css class "NSE_View_Delete". appended

I want to change and append other css class dynamically..

```
@Html.Hidden("ViewGroupDetails", Url.Action("ViewGroupDetails", "NSEDownload", new { acid = InsiderTrading.Common.ConstEnum.UserActions.NSEDownload }), new { @class = "gridtypecontrol", ctrtype = "link", gridcolumntype = @ViewBag.GridType + "_usr_grd_11073", param = "{'text':'','href':'" + Url.Action("ViewGroupDetails", "NSEDownload", new { acid = InsiderTrading.Common.ConstEnum.UserActions.NSEDownload }) + "&GroupId=<GroupId>','class':'NSE_View_Delete','text':'View/Delete'}" })
```

```js
if (obj.aData['nse_grd_50431'] != null) {
  var abc = obj.aData['nse_grd_50431'];
  if (abc == 0) {
    $('#ViewGroupDetails').addClass('loading123').removeClass('NSE_View_Delete');
  }
```

The hidden field rendered in the browser as follows:

```
<a href="/NSEDownload/ViewGroupDetails?acid=223&amp;GroupId=773" class="NSE_View_Delete">View/Delete</a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What you have should work fine. Note that the HTML source will not change in the 'View Source' window - you would need to see the change in the DOM Inspector instead.

Comment: You show only href, not full hidden field. Also - do you have only one this hidden field on your View?

Comment: Are you running your jQuery code in $(document).ready(...)?

Comment: Hi freedomn-m, due my project arch. in need to do that., I want to append new css class in jquery

Answer (score 0):

In order to set `class` property of an element using `jQuery` you can try this:

```
$("#elementId").removeClass("removed-css-class"); //first remove the class
$("#elementId").addClass("added-css-class"); //then set classs
```